# How to train my ChatterBot model using GPU instead of CPU

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot

I am using chatterbot library to develop a chatbot. I want to train the chatbot using my GPU instead of my CPU

Here is my code:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer


bot = ChatBot(
    #Bot name
    "Elon"
)

trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(bot)

trainer.train(
    'chatterbot.corpus.english'
)

while True:

    user_input = input('You: ')
    bot_response = bot.get_response(user_input)
    print(bot_response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at chatterbot's documentation, there is nothing mentioned about that.
But maybe you can look at the framework that it was built on and try to change the sourcecode to allow GPU training.

Comment: What is am looking for is a library or a way i can implement gpu training in my code

Comment: Since you are using their trainer, and since their trainer doesn't support gpu training, then you can't add that. To do this you have to make your own network and train it in the way that you like, maybe using tensorflow/pytorch for example.

Comment: And what is should do it use the trained data i trained from pytorch or tensor flow in implementing it into my code